# How to use Solr's parallel SQL and Streaming expressions with collections residing on multi cloud environments

Tags: solr, apache-spark-sql, solrcloud, lucidworks

We are exploring streaming expressions, parallel SQL in Solr to use in our current project. In our use case, we need to join two collections one residing on private datacenter and other on public cloud. I was reading through Solr's [reference guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/streaming-expressions.html) and blog post from [lucidworks](https://lucidworks.com/post/solr-as-sparksql-datasource-part-ii/) . Examples were demonstrated with collections residing on same Solr's engine.

Is is possible to use Parallel SQL or Streaming expressions with collections residing on different environments?

We are using spark with solr(7.x) as one of the datasource, and lucidworks-spark-solr 3.4.5 connector

Comment: I dont think this is possible to read data from 2 different places. Streaming expression can bring the data from same solr engine having multiple collections...But it wont bring the data from 2 different collection which are residing in 2 different solr search engine which are hosted at 2 diffrent places

Comment: You can give the `zkHost` argument to the `search` stream source in Streaming expressions - in effect reading from a collection on a different cluster. You do _not_ want to expose your zookeeper ensemble anywhere public, so set up private networking between the two hosts - then you should be able to access both zk environments from the same streaming expression.

Comment: zkHost: Only needs to be defined if the collection being searched is found in a different zkHost than the local stream handler. - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/stream-source-reference.html#search-parameters